# How to store user input into list on Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I'm having a bit of trouble putting user inputs into a list. 
I basically want the user to input about 5 thing and have each item stored in the list individually. I then want to display all the input in said list. If anyone can give any bit of guidance it will be greatly appreciated.
This is what i have so far:

```
mylist=[1,2,3,4,5]

print mylist

print"Enter 5 items on shopping list"

for i in mylist:
    shopping=raw_input()

print shopping
```

Comment: Have you looked at the python docs? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: thanks I am using the link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly urge you to read through the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) which provide you with some basic examples of list operation - open up a shell, and type those examples out for yourself. Basically you want to store someone's *input* into `mylist`, so there is no need to predefine it with values:

`mylist=[]`

Now you want to prompt a user 5 times (to enter 5 items):

```
print "Enter 5 items on shopping list"
for i in xrange(5): # range starts from 0 and ends at 5-1 (so 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 executes your loop contents 5 times)
    shopping = raw_input()
    mylist.append(shopping) # add input to the list

print mylist # at this point your list contains the 5 things entered by user
```

Comment: `xrange(5)` or `range(5)`. It starts at `0` but it ends at `4`.

Comment: @KlausD. you're right, sorry I'm somewhat slow tonight.

Answer (score 2):

This is my way of storing input into a list:

```
list = []
i = 1
while i < 6:
    a = input("Please enter " + str(i) +  " list : ")
    list.append(a)
    i+=1
print(list)
```

Comment: why would you use `while` with `i+=1` instead of for and range?